# Problems with zheev routine in fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran, lapack

I'm trying to write a program which computes the hamiltonian of a ising system. The first part of the program works, and i obtain the matrix that i want, but a problem occurs when i try to get the eigenvalues of this complex*16 matrix by using the subroutine zheev. As i read i have to call it 2 times, in order to assign the best possible value to the integer lwork. But for the given matrix, instead of getting the eigenvalues (-2.236, -1, 1, 2.236), as matlab does, i get (132, 0, 1, 0). Could somebody help me?

Thank you very much

```
module matrices
 implicit none
 type matrix
    complex*16, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: el
    integer :: row, col
 end type

 contains 

    type(matrix) function assign0(row, col)
       integer :: ii, jj, row, col
       assign0%row = row
       assign0%col = col
       allocate(assign0%el(assign0%row, assign0%col))
       do ii = 1, assign0%row
          do jj = 1, assign0%col
             assign0%el(ii, jj) = cmplx(0d0, 0d0)
          enddo
       enddo
    end function assign0

    type(matrix) function assignid(row, col)
       integer :: ii, jj, row, col
       assignid%row = row
       assignid%col = col
       allocate(assignid%el(assignid%row, assignid%col))
       do ii = 1, assignid%row
          jj = ii
          assignid%el(ii, jj) = cmplx(1d0, 0d0)
       enddo
    end function assignid

    type(matrix) function assignsigx()
       allocate(assignsigx%el(assignsigx%row, assignsigx%col))         
       assignsigx = assign0(2, 2)
       assignsigx%el(1, 2) = (1d0, 0d0)
       assignsigx%el(2, 1) = (1d0, 0d0)
    end function 

    type(matrix) function assignsigz() 
       allocate(assignsigz%el(assignsigz%row, assignsigz%col))
       assignsigz = assign0(2, 2)
       assignsigz%el(1, 1) = (1d0, 0d0)
       assignsigz%el(2, 2) = (-1d0, 0d0)
    end function

    type(matrix) function prodscal(lambda, ma1)
       type(matrix) :: ma1
       real :: lambda
       integer :: ii, jj
       prodscal%row = ma1%row
       prodscal%col = ma1%col
       allocate(prodscal%el(prodscal%row, prodscal%col))
       do ii = 1, ma1%row
          do jj = 1, ma1%col
             prodscal%el(ii, jj) = lambda*ma1%el(ii, jj)
          enddo
       enddo
    end function prodscal

    type(matrix) function matsum(ma1, ma2, sign)
       type(matrix) :: ma1, ma2
       integer :: ii, jj, sign
       matsum%row = ma1%row
       matsum%col = ma1%col
       allocate(matsum%el(matsum%row, matsum%col))
       do ii = 1, ma1%row
          do jj = 1, ma1%col
             if (sign .gt. 0) then
                matsum%el(ii, jj) = ma1%el(ii, jj) + ma2%el(ii, jj)
             else
                matsum%el(ii, jj) = ma1%el(ii, jj) - ma2%el(ii, jj)
             endif
          enddo
       enddo       
    end function matsum

    type(matrix) function tensprod(ma1, ma2)
       type(matrix) :: ma1, ma2
       integer :: ii, jj, kk, ll
       tensprod%row = ma1%row*ma2%row
       tensprod%col = ma1%col*ma2%col
       allocate(tensprod%el(tensprod%row, tensprod%col))
       tensprod = assign0(tensprod%row, tensprod%col)
       do ii = 1, ma1%row
          do jj = 1, ma1%col
             do kk = 1, ma2%row
                do ll = 1, ma2%col
                   tensprod%el((ii - 1)*ma2%row + kk, (jj - 1)*ma2%col + ll) = ma1%el(ii, jj)*ma2%el(kk, ll)
                enddo
             enddo
          enddo
       enddo
    end function tensprod

 end module matrices

    program test
       use matrices
       implicit none

       interface 
          function getdim()
             integer :: getdim
          end function getdim
       end interface

       integer :: row, col, ii, jj, N, ind, info, lwork, aus
       type(matrix), dimension(2, 2) :: arrmat1, arrmat2
       type(matrix), dimension(2) :: element1, element2, element3
       type(matrix) :: elementtot, elementtot1, elementtot2
       real :: lambda
       double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: w, rwork
       complex*16, dimension(:), allocatable :: work
       N = 2        

       allocate(w(15))
       allocate(rwork(15))
       allocate(work(15))

       lwork = -1
       aus = 2
       lambda = 1d0
       do ii = 1, N
          ind = ii
          do jj = 1, N
             if(jj .eq. ind) then
                arrmat1(ii, jj) = assignsigz()
             else
                arrmat1(ii, jj) = assignid(2, 2)
             endif
          enddo
       enddo

       do ii = 1, N
          ind = ii
          do jj = 1, N
             if(jj .eq. ind) then
                arrmat2(ii, jj) = assignsigx()
             else
                arrmat2(ii, jj) = assignid(2, 2)
             endif
          enddo
       enddo

       do ii = 1, N
          element1(ii) = tensprod(arrmat1(ii, 1), arrmat1(ii, 2))
          if (N .gt. 2) then
             do jj = 3, N
                element1(ii) = tensprod(element1(ii), arrmat1(ii, jj))
             enddo
          endif
       enddo

       do ii = 1, N
          element2(ii) = tensprod(arrmat2(ii, 1), arrmat2(ii, 2))
          if (N .gt. 2) then
             do jj = 3, N
                element2(ii) = tensprod(element2(ii), arrmat2(ii, jj))
             enddo
          endif
       enddo              

       do ii = 1, N - 1              
          element3(ii) = assign0(2**N, 2**N)
          element3(ii)%el = matmul(element2(ii + 1)%el, element2(ii)%el)
       enddo

       elementtot = assign0(2**N, 2**N)
       elementtot1 = assign0(2**N, 2**N)
       elementtot2 = assign0(2**N, 2**N)

       do ii = 1, N 
          elementtot1 = matsum(elementtot1, element1(ii), 1)
       enddo

       do ii = 1, N - 1
          elementtot2 = matsum(elementtot2, element3(ii), 1)
       enddo

       elementtot2 = prodscal(lambda, elementtot2)

       elementtot = matsum(elementtot1, elementtot2, 1)

       do ii = 1, 2**N 
          write(*,'(20G12.4)') elementtot%el(ii, 1:2**N)
       enddo                   

       call zheev('N', 'U', 2**N, elementtot%el, 2**N, w, work, lwork, rwork, info)
       lwork = int(work(1))
       call zheev('N', 'U', 2**N, elementtot%el, 2**N, w, work, lwork, rwork, info)           

       print*, '***', info

       do ii = 1, 2**N
          write(*,'(20G12.4)') work(ii)
       enddo

       stop

    end program test
```

Comment: I haven't looked closely, but you do a workspace query, and then do nothing to resize the workspace to the optimal size, (but tell the subroutine it's of that size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `assignsigx` and `assignsigz` functions are allocating space for their return values based on undefined values of the `row` and `col` components of the respective return value. You probably want to pass in the `row` and `col` sizes you want to use, just as you do in the `assign0` and `assignid` functions. Either that or just take out the Allocate lines referencing the undefined components and let the subsequent assignments using `assign0` handle it?

If I take out lines 33 and 39, compiling and running using the NAG Fortran Compiler with full checking turned on tells me

```
Extension: test.f90, line 4: Byte count on numeric data type
           detected at *@16
Extension: test.f90, line 112: Byte count on numeric data type
           detected at *@16
Questionable: test.f90, line 199: Variable AUS set but never referenced
Warning: test.f90, line 199: Unused local variable COL
Warning: test.f90, line 199: Unused interface for procedure GETDIM
Warning: test.f90, line 199: Unused local variable ROW
Questionable: test.f90, line 17: Intrinsic function CMPLX with double precision argument and no KIND= argument returns single precision result
Questionable: test.f90, line 29: Intrinsic function CMPLX with double precision argument and no KIND= argument returns single precision result
[NAG Fortran Compiler normal termination, 8 warnings]
Runtime Error: test.f90, line 87: Reference to undefined variable MA2%EL(KK,LL)
Program terminated by fatal error
Abort (core dumped)
```

The crash is in the first call to `tensprod`, at line 145, when `ii` is `1`. The `kk` and `ll` in `ma2%el(kk,ll)` are `1` and `2` respectively. This seems to be because you have not zeroed the off-diagonal elements in `assignid`. If I also do this, then I see

```
Extension: test.f90, line 4: Byte count on numeric data type
           detected at *@16
Extension: test.f90, line 113: Byte count on numeric data type
           detected at *@16
Questionable: test.f90, line 200: Variable AUS set but never referenced
Warning: test.f90, line 200: Unused local variable COL
Warning: test.f90, line 200: Unused interface for procedure GETDIM
Warning: test.f90, line 200: Unused local variable ROW
Questionable: test.f90, line 17: Intrinsic function CMPLX with double precision argument and no KIND= argument returns single precision result
Questionable: test.f90, line 30: Intrinsic function CMPLX with double precision argument and no KIND= argument returns single precision result
[NAG Fortran Compiler normal termination, 8 warnings]
   2.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       1.000       0.000    
   0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       1.000       0.000       0.000       0.000    
   0.000       0.000       1.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000    
   1.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000      -2.000       0.000    
Runtime Error: zheev.f90, line 1: Invalid reference to procedure ZHEEV - Dummy array WORK (number 7) has 36 elements but actual argument only has 15 elements
Program terminated by fatal error
Abort (core dumped)
```

So I think it certainly is the case that your omission of resizing `work` is a problem, as francescalus noted.

If I resize `work` according to the new `lwork` (by deallocating it and allocating it again) I get results

```
   2.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       1.000       0.000    
   0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       1.000       0.000       0.000       0.000    
   0.000       0.000       1.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000    
   1.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000      -2.000       0.000    
 *** 0
   36.00       0.000    
   0.000       0.000    
   1.000       0.000
```

As an aside, why are you ending with printing `work`? The only thing of interest there should be `work(1)`, when doing a workspace query.